# Changing the volume of an SCNAudioPlayer in real time - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, audio, scenekit, avaudioengine

I am trying to work out how I can changed the volume of an `SCNAudioPlayer` in real time.

Currently, I have an `SCNAudioSource` connected to an `SCNAudioPlayer`. This audio player is then assigned to a `SCNNode` so that my sound makes use of SceneKits spatial audio processing.

As it stands, I am able to change the volume of each `SCNNode` using `SCNAudioSource.volume` triggered by the boolean variable `vol`. An extract of my code for this is shown below:

```
(audioSource, audioCount) = soundFileSelect(audioFileIndex: 0) 
    audioSource?.isPositional = true 
    if vol {
        audioSource?.volume = 1.0
    }
    else {
        audioSource?.volume = 0.0
    }
    let audioPlayer = SCNAudioPlayer(source: audioSource!) 
    geometryNode.addAudioPlayer(audioPlayer) 
    let play = SCNAction.playAudio(audioSource!, waitForCompletion: true) 
    let loopPlay = SCNAction.repeatForever(play) 
    geometryNode.runAction(loopPlay)
```

However, this only changes the default volume setting of the source, and so only happens when the node is spawned. I am trying to change the volume of it in real time, after a button press.

I feel I am missing something simple, and have trolled the internet for  documentation and examples but am really struggling. From Apple's API documentation I am fairly certain it can be done. As far as I can tell you have to use the `audioNode` property associated with the `SCNAudioPlayer` which forms part of the `AVAudioMixing` protocol. Using this `AVAudioMxing` volume property should be what I need!

However, for the life of me I can't work out how to implement this process in code within my current setup. I can access `mainMixer.volume`/`outputvolume` such as:

```
audioPlayer.audioNode?.engine?.mainMixerNode.outputVolume=0
```

but this doesn't seem to work. How do the AV and SCN components link together?

Any help or examples of how one goes about implementing this would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

```
guard let avNode = playerGuitar?.audioNode as? AVAudioMixing else {
      return
}
avNode.volume = volume
```

worked in my code (took ages to find though, and being new to swift didn't exactly help). playerGuitar is a SCNAudioPlayer variable.

Answer (score 0):

Very belated: This code appears to work, might want to ensure there is only one audioPlayer:

```
guard let player = scnNode.audioPlayers.first?.audioNode as? AVAudioMixing else {
    return
}

player.volume = // a value between 0.0..1.0
```